# how to show the foreground of a class filled with a certain color or image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

suppose i have the following code:

```
 <a class="admin" href="do_with_logo.php">


 <div class="logo">
 <img src="uploads/<?php echo $item ?>"  >
 </div> <!-- end of class logo-->


 </a> <!-- end of class admin>-->
```

When I  hover mouse on the 'admin' class i want the full area of the class to show red color. That is whatever exists in the 'admin' class, mouse hovered on the class will make it show up prominently red. No problem if the content behind looks blurred or invisible.

I need it to give  the admin panel the ability to hover mouse on the homepage and see which part they can change with dynamic input i.e. area showing red color can take them to the dynamic input page of that corresponding area on mouseclick.

Thanks in advance
Istiaque Ahmed
Bangladesh

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're wanting to fill the box with a solid color, hiding the elements inside (while keeping the dimensions consistent). I went with the following (online at http://jsfiddle.net/2rhKC/)

```
<a class="admin" href="do_with_logo.php">
    <span>Hello World. This is my text.</span>
</a>

a.admin {
 display:inline-block;
 padding:5px 10px;
 background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
a.admin:hover {
 background-color:#a52401;   
}
a.admin:hover span {
 visibility:hidden;   
}
```

You'll note that I'm styling my `a` with an `inline-block` declaration, and removing the inner `div` element. Also, when I hover the link we set the visibility of the immediate child element (a `span` in this case) to `hidden`. All of your child elements should go within the `span`, thus all will be hidden when you mouse over the link.

Comment: Should I replace ur 'span' with my 'logo' class?

Comment: @sof_user You don't need to. Just put all of your stuff inside a span element, and you can use my CSS as-is: `<a><span><!-- Your HTML Here --></span></a>` for example.

Comment: suppose instead of showing red color, i want to add a transparent image that will let the content show up blurred , any suggestions plz?

Comment: @sof_user You won't be able to blur the content - HTML/CSS isn't really capable of this right now. You may be able to acheive something close with drop-shadows, but the support will be somewhat sketchy across multiple browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.admin').hover(function(){
  $(this).attr('style', 'background-color:red');
});
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: how and where should i write it? by the. I deleted an answer from this page mistakenly I assume. How I can get that back , can anyone tell me plz?

Answer (score 0):

The foreground-color in CSS only affects text, like defined here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#foreground - If you want some kind of overlay in your element, you'd have to create a dedicated markup-element like an image for this.

Suppose you have div or p with class admin that contains your interactive elements:

```
<div class="admin">
    <img class="overlay" src="some/path/overlay.png" alt="">
    <a class="admin_link" href="do_with_logo.php">Do sth.</a>
</div>
```

Now you define a CSS rule to show the overlay-image when users hover over the admin-div:

```
div.admin:hover .overlay {display:block;}
```

Otherwise the image is hidden:

```
div.admin .overlay {display:none;}
```

The image should also strech to the whole width + height of the parent div

```
div.admin .overlay {width:100%;height:100%}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where is the logo class? plz notice that i wanted to have a link (<a ..> </a> ) around a div.

Comment: @sof_user: the anchor-tag can only contain inline elements, hence the missing div inside. see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-A

Comment: no the overlaying image shows up in its original dimension. and if i write the 'logo' class inside the admin class, the logo image shows twice. solution plz...

Comment: suppose, i want to add a transparent overlaying image, any suggestion? i don't find any such image.

Comment: @sof_user: regarding the double logo: can't really say sth. about this without having seen the actual code.
About the transparent image: Open GIMP, create new image or use existing image as a new layer. Then silde back the control element for layer opacity and save image as PNG incuding alpha-transparency.